# Visual studio is unable to start program when trying to render something on the glfw window with glfw(C++)

Tags: c++, glfw

When i'm rendering nothing on the glfw window everything works fine but when I try to add something like glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) or legacy OpenGL visual studio gives me an error :
"Unable to start prgram {path to the .exe file} file specified is not found".
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
  GLFWwindow* window;
  
  if (!glwfInit())
    return -1

  window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);

  if (!window)
  {
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
  }

  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

  while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
  {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
  }

  glfwTerminate();
  return 0;
}
```

So as you see, there is this glClear(params) but when there isnt glClear(params) i do not get any errors and the window is rendered to the screen but there is glClear(params) i get the error "Unable to start program..."

Answer (score 0):

"file specified is not found" shows that compilation failed and no executable was built. Try a rebuild and check the list of compilation errors.

Comment: so i compiled and it give me this error : >Application.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glClear referenced in function main ( by the  way i installed glfw with vcpkg )

Comment: This function is found in Opengl32.lib. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/opengl/glclear